# Doxygen+PHP link to other class member

Tags: php, doxygen

I'm documenting a PHP project with Doxygen instead of phpDocs because the project involves COCOA programming so I decide to use a common documentation tool.

I have no problem linking to other class methods using the syntax `ClassName::method name()`

but I get no link when trying to reach a class member in another class, be it public or private with the syntax `ClassName::varName`.

In one file.

```
class A {
    /**
    * A Member
    */
    private $a;
    /**
    * A method
    */
    public myMethod(){}
}
```

In other file.

```
/**
* Doxygen block
*
* This link is not working!!
* A::a
* This one the same!
* A::$a
*
* This link is working:
* A::myMethod().
*/
```

UPDATED:
It's working now, the syntax `ClassName::varName`is now working. Can't tell what was wrong before so sorry for this useless question. I will mark it as answered as soon as the system allows me to answer my own question.

Comment: Have you set the `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` option to `YES` in your configuration file?